# Get Local Coordinates of MovieClip in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, coordinates, point, movieclip

I need to get the coordinates of a MovieClip according to another nested MovieClip in Actionscript 3.

Here's the context of MovieClip1:

```
Stage > Container > MovieClip1
```

Here's the context of MovieClip2:

```
Stage > Container > OtherMovieClip > MovieClip2
```

I'm trying to get the coordinates (X, Y) of MovieClip1 according to MovieClip2. For example, once I get the coordinates, I could set the X and Y of another MovieClip inside MovieClip2 so that it would be at the same coordinates as MovieClip1.

I've tried working with localToGlobal and globalToLocal but I can't get the result that I am trying to achieve.

**EDIT:**

Here's the code I've tried:

```
var localPoint:Point = new Point(MovieClip1.x, MovieClip1.y);
var globalPoint:Point = MovieClip2.localToGlobal(localPoint);
var containerLocalPoint:Point = Container.globalToLocal(globalPoint);
```

Comment: Try _getBounds_ (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#getBounds%28%29)

Comment: I don't think getBounds will help as it returns a Rectangle, not a Point.

Comment: just create _new Point(rect.x, rect.y)_

Comment: What do you mean by "can't get the result that I am trying to achieve"? Can you put some example numbers of what you expect what localToGlobal and globalToLocal give out?

Comment: Would be good to just post the code that didn't work. So we can see your logic in using `localToGlobal` and `globalToLocal`. They do indeed work, so this is a question of whether your logic is sound or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I am understanding you correctly, but here's what I think you want to do :

1. Get the global location of MovieClip1 using localToGlobal.
2. Convert that global location to a local location within MovieClip2 using globalToLocal.
3. Use that location to set the x,y of your 3rd clip inside MovieClip2

I could code this out for you, but I think you are best helped by examining the logic of this solution and utilizing that to solve your problem.

If the logic is not the problem, then the question is really "How do I use localToGlobal and/or globalToLocal ?", which has surely been answered on this site, so a quick search can help you with the details.

Comment: Thanks for the logic. Worked as I implemented it.